# How to run docker-comopse on a Jenkins pipeline agent?

Tags: docker, jenkins, makefile, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I have Jenkins running on an EC2 instance. I also have installed docker on it. I am using a pipeline job and want to run tests using docker-compose. What is the pipeline agent that I can use?

The agent should be able to handle `docker-compose` and `make`commands.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this but I am not using docker-Compose.Instead of that I am Using normal docker file.I have done similar to this.

```
pipeline {
agent { dockerfile true }
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'node --version'
            sh 'svn --version'
        }
    }
}
```

You can also find here for more https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/